# Paramter is missing a value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I'm calling a Detail report from the summary report and my summary report field is passed as a parameter to the detail report. However when clicking on certain rows based on one condition, the detail report opens correctly.
Certain rows shows the type parameter is missing.

I am passing the type value while invoking the reports and value is passed from the type field in the summary report

```
Eg IF(@type=''A'')
EXEC AcceptedDetail
If (@type = ''R'')
EXEC AcceptedDetail
```

In this case R works fine while A does not.

Comment: where do you use your if statement? Dataset? Why not pass the  @type as a parameter to the stored procedure?

Comment: Its inside a Store Procedure and @type parameter is passed in the Store Procedure. It works for a certain value and not for another value. Can that happen

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DECLARE @type CHAR(1) = 'R'

IF @type IN ('A','R')
BEGIN
   EXEC AcceptedDetail
END
```